# Financial Statements from Yahoo-Managed

Tags: c#, .net, finance, yahoo-finance

is there a way to get Balance Sheet / Income Statement / Etc out of Yahoo-Managed?  Anyone know any alternatives if there isn't?

Comment: This is the exact same question you posted yesterday. Rather than open a new question, continue with the original one as this question is destined for premature-closure.

Answer (score -1):

```
using MaasOne.Finance.YahooFinance

    CompanyStatisticsDownload dl = new CompanyStatisticsDownload();
    dl.Settings.ID = "YHOO";
    Response<CompanyStatisticsResult> resp = dl.Download();
    if (resp.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Success)
    {
        CompanyFinancialHighlights hl = resp.Result.Item.FinancialHighlights;
        double ebitda = hl.EBITDAInMillion * Math.Pow(10, 6);
        //...
    }
```

Comment: I've used Yahoo-Managed...but it doesn't seem to have any balance sheet stuff in it.